# DocsList.createFile sometimes creates blank or corrupted PDF

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a google document (I would love to create it as HTML if this could work that way) then export that document as a pdf to send as an email attachment. Here is the basic structure that I have

```
var docName = "test";

var doc = DocumentApp.create(docName);
doc.appendParagraph("Hello World");

DocsList.createFile(docName, doc.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes(), 'application/pdf');
```

But this behaves oddly. Sometimes it creates a blank pdf, sometimes a corrupted one that doesn't open with the message "Sorry, we are unable to generate a view of the document at this time. Please try again later."

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important that you save and close the file before converting it to pdf. If you don't call `saveAndClose()`, your changes will still be pending. Just do

```
doc.saveAndClose();
DocsList.createFile(doc.getAs('application/pdf')).rename(docName);
```

In my experience, it has been much cleaner to handle documents in blobs instead of byte arrays. So this should work cleanly and as expected.

Comment: This creates a pdf that can open, but it is blank. I did verify that the google doc that it creates from has content.